# Raise Validation Error Instantly in Django Forms

Tags: django, django-forms

I am working with a ModelForm that looks like this:

```
class TestForm(forms.ModelForm):   
    class Meta:
        model = TestModel
        fields = ('name', 'description', 'date')
        widgets = {
            'execution_date': forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}),
        }
```

What I' m hoping to do is look at the `date` field and make sure it is today's date or a future date before submitting the form, the same way an `EmailField`raises and error instantly if you enter an address without the @ sign and try to move on.

Normally I'd let the user hit submit, then check the date and return the form if things don't look right, however I am working with stripe and the submit button actually triggers a Stripe check out then validates the form which would charge the customer twice if they had en error. Any ideas on how I can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Making this validation before submitting is possible through javascript. The best way to do this is through widget: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/widgets/

EmailField does not have this need because it is an email-type input, and HTML already fills this validation.

But it is still recommended that you validate directly on the Form, for security reasons.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. [Link-only](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Douglas, could you specify a little more on how I could use widgets to accomplish this. I'm looking at the `SelectDateWidget` and that seems to take a range of dates rather thank limiting the selection to future dates only. Thanks.